# How can I loop over a list four elements at a time?

Tags: perl, loops

This is a slice from an otherwise successful script.  What I need it to do is print one `<tr>` then print `<td>$stat_array</td>` four times, quit, print a `</tr>` then print another `<tr>`, print the next four `$stat_arrays` in `@stat_array`, and so on and then a `</table>`.

What it does is print all eight `$start_arrays` then a `</tr>`.

```
my @table_header = ("Process", "Region_Permission","Region Violation","Message Type");
my @stat_array =("ibfarm102  - localtick" ," Greenwich" ," hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 -     Hongkong" , "PidMonRsp" ," ibfarm102  - localtick", "Greenwich" ,"hibmis100 -      procHKHD2 - Hongkong", "PidMonReq");

print MAIL "<tr>\n";

for ($i = 0 ; $i <$#table_header ; $i = $i + $#table_header) {
    foreach my $stat_array(@stat_array) {
        print MAIL "<td>$stat_array</td>\n";
    }

    print MAIL "</tr>\n";
}
print MAIL "</table>\n";
print MAIL "<br><br>\n";
print MAIL "</table></center></body></html>";
close MAIL;
```

what i get:

```
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td> Greenwich</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonRsp</td>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td> Greenwich</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonReq</td>
</tr>
```

I need the table to look like :

```
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td> Greenwich</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonRsp</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ibfarm102  - localtick </td>
<td> Greenwich</td>
<td> hibmis100 -  procHKHD2 - Hongkong </td>
<td>PidMonReq</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like a good candidate for [`List::MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils)' `natatime` (n-at-a-time) function:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';

my $four_at_a_time = natatime 4, @stat_array;
my $string_to_print = "<html><body><center><table>\n";

while ( my @four = $four_at_a_time->() ) {

    $string_to_print .= join "\n", "<tr>",
                                   map { "<td>" . $_ . "</td>" } @four,
                                   "</tr>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `every` function from my module [List::Gen](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aGen) allows you to walk any array with a variable step size:

```
my @array = 1..10;

for (every 4 => @array) {
    print "@$_\n";
}
```

which prints:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10
```

Unlike `natatime` or splicing a copy of the array, the elements in the `for` loop are aliased to the elements of `@array` so you can change them in the loop if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution: Inside your for loop, whenever `i` has become a multiple of 4 other than 0 and other than the last item in the array, print `</tr><tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all you don't need the outer loop at all since the condition:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <$#table_header ; $i = $i + $#table_header)
```

will only ever execute the containing block only once!   Now to separate every fourth element in @stat_array with a `"<tr>"`, simply do this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $#stat_array; ++$i) {
        print MAIL "<td>$stat_array[$i]</td>\n";
        print MAIL "<tr>" if ($i % 4 == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
# make a copy of the stats if you need the original array left intact
my @stat_array_rows = @stat_array;
while (my @stat_array_row = splice(@stat_array_rows, 0, 4)) {
    print MAIL "<tr>\n";
    for my $stat (@stat_array_row) {
        print MAIL "<td>$stat</td>\n";
    }
    print MAIL "</tr>\n";
}
```